# Reading LLVM DAG

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to examine the DAG through all of the stages in order to determine where an instruction selection is going wrong. But I'm not sure how to interpret some of the notation in the output DAG.

First the LLVM-ir for the function:

```
define i32 @get_data() #0 {
entry:
  %0 = load i32* @data, align 4
  ret i32 %0
}
```

I ran llc with -debug and I see the initial selection DAG for the function I'm interested in is:

```
=== get_data
Initial selection DAG: BB#0 'get_data:entry'
SelectionDAG has 8 nodes:
 0x38d60f0: ch = EntryToken

  0x3902cf0: i64 = Constant<0>

  0x3903020: i32 = Register %R1

    0x38d60f0: <multiple use>
    0x3903020: <multiple use>
      0x38d60f0: <multiple use>
      0x3902be0: i64 = GlobalAddress<i32* @data> 0 [ORD=2]

      0x3902e00: i64 = undef

    0x3902f10: i32,ch = load 0x38d60f0, 0x3902be0,   0x3902e00<LD4[@data]> [ORD=2]

  0x3903130: ch,glue = CopyToReg 0x38d60f0, 0x3903020, 0x3902f10 [ORD=3]

    0x3903130: <multiple use>
    0x3903020: <multiple use>
    0x3903130: <multiple use>
```

I'm wondering about the load instruction above, specifically the third operand:

```
0x3902e00<LD4[@data]>
```

I can tell that from above the node 0x3902e00 is undefined, but how should I read the part between '<' and '>'? What does this construct mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the memory operations nodes also capture the memory reference which is affected by an operation. This reference is described via MachineMemOperand class and you can grab it out of the node using getMemOperand() call. What you're seeing inside is the contents of the MachineMemOperand. Here basically it says that it's a load of size 4 of IR value @base.

See MachineMemOperand::print() for more information. It might also include bunch of other stuff including the offset, address space, AA information, whether the load / store is non-temporal and so on.